# unity 5.6.0b7 vr stereoscopic panorama + 3d objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr, stereoscopy

I have 2 textures to create stereoscopic panorama on VR and i want to make a 360º experience. In order to achieve this I need to show one texture at the left side (VR-LeftEye) and the other at the right side (VR-RightEye). Additionally i have to show 3D models in front of the panorama to interact with them.

Im using cardboard GoogleVR v1.20 with Unity 5.6.0b7. I have no problem with changing any version.

After several researches i got few possible solutions but i dont know how to implement them at 100%:

- 2 spheres (with the faces inside) with 1 camera at the center of the spheres and cull the left on the right side and viceversa. I don know how to cull in different ways per side because only one camera is needed to make stereo in 5.6.
- 2 textures in the same sphere material and the shader should select the needed texture according to the rendering side. I dont know how to know what is the rendering side in the shader code.
- 2 spheres, 2 cameras.This is the most artisan way and i have some issues displaying the 3d objects and i got double rotation speed.

Any tips or solutions are welcome.

**EDIT:**
*Im looking for a solution on Unity 5.6.0 because it just implemented a feature that make 2 projections with a distance between them simulating both eyes.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with VR in unity, but 3rd option sounds better because of the additional 3D models in front of the panorama.
Furthermore, since the eyes are in the center of the spheres in this implementation, moving 3D objects in front of the cameras might be tricky.

Comment: Unity 5.6.0 just implemented a feature that make 2 projections with a distance between them simulating both eyes. Thx anyway!